# How to send x-www-form-urlencoded request with python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem with sending a request to an endpoint.

```
draft_content = body_serializer.data['content']
        recipient_stream_id = user_to.zulip_id
        topic = "draft"
        draft_type = "private"

        data = {"draft" : {
            "content": draft_content,
            "to": [recipient_stream_id],
            "topic": topic,
            "type": draft_type
        }}

        try:
            response = requests.patch(
                f'{settings.ZULIP_SITE}api/v1/drafts/{draft_id}',
                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                json=urlencode(data),
                auth=(user.zulip_email, user.zulip_api_key),
                verify=False
            )
            result = response.json()  # Преобразование JSON-ответа в словарь
        except Exception as err:
            return Response(
                {'message': f'Error editing draft: {err}'},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            )

        if result["result"] == 'error':
            return Response(
                {'message': result},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )
        elif result["result"] == 'success':
            response_data = ZulipEditDraftResponse(
                data={
                    'result': str(result["result"]),
                }
            )
```

I am getting

```json
{
  "message": {
    "result": "error",
    "msg": "Missing 'draft' argument", 
    "var_name":"draft", 
    "code":"REQUEST_VARIABLE_MISSING"
  }
}
```

I tried to send the same request with Postman and got the same message. But after I changed the body type from `raw` to `x-www-form-urlencoded`, it worked.

Here's the equivalent `curl` command from postman:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'http://api.pets.kruts.net/api/v1/zulip/draft/edit/2/' \
--header 'Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjkyMDkzMzM5LCJqdGkiOiJjY2ZlZmNkMmJhNWY0ZWZiYWRlY2Y1ZGQ3NzA3NTMyNSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjg0OX0.rk4vSSQ_LVT3OQFXuFW21pg1FacKhgRLOHYWdprCnDY' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'email_to=+380635990523@mail.com' \
--data-urlencode 'content=helooo'
```

How to do the same from Python?

I tried to use `json.dumps` and `urlencode`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to send payload in the `json` param, use the `data` param which accepts a list or tuples. See the [documentation](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/src/requests/api.py#L133C37-L133C37)

```py
import requests
import urllib.parse

url = "http://api.pets.kruts.net/api/v1/zulip/draft/edit/2/"

data = {"draft": {
            "content": draft_content,
            "to": [recipient_stream_id],
            "topic": topic,
            "type": draft_type
        }}

payload = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjkyMDkzMzM5LCJqdGkiOiJjY2ZlZmNkMmJhNWY0ZWZiYWRlY2Y1ZGQ3NzA3NTMyNSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjg0OX0.rk4vSSQ_LVT3OQFXuFW21pg1FacKhgRLOHYWdprCnDY',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: and how to form it in

data = {"draft" : {
            "content": draft_content,
            "to": [recipient_stream_id],
            "topic": topic,
            "type": draft_type
        }}